# MySQL NOT IN Syntax convertible to JOINs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select full_name, email, users.uid
from
cloudsponge
inner join 
`users` on users.uid = cloudsponge.importer_uid
where cloudsponge.email not in (select mail from users)
```

It works as expected but I'm wondering, can I convert the last line to a join (rather than a subquery). This would be helpful as I can use my frameworks ORM rather than hardcode SQL into the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
SELECT full_name, email, users.uid
  FROM cloudsponge
 INNER
  JOIN users
    ON users.uid = cloudsponge.importer_uid
  LEFT
  JOIN users AS users2
    ON cloudsponge.email = users2.mail
 WHERE users2.mail IS NULL
```

Comment: FYI: I can't tell you why, but I've been told by two different DBA's that this is not good practice. I don't know if it's just because they didn't like the style, or if the optimizer doesn't like it, or if some RDBMS's don't work. But they've told me to use the `not in` or `not exists` technique instead.

Comment: @JoeEnos: Personally, I don't like the style: `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are expressing the actual intent, whereas `LEFT JOIN` + `IS NULL` is a hackish way to express it as a join. But if you want to know why those DBAs objected to it, you should ask them!

Comment: @JoeEnos, I've seen both solutions perform better, but it depends on a lot of things, like the RDBMS optimizer, the volume of data being scanned, etc.  Best to test both solutions for a given case.  See my presentation [SQL Query Patterns, Optimized](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized).

Comment: @ruakh The answer I got back then was that it "doesn't always work". I don't believe that, at least in the system we were using (Oracle) - I tested it out several times and it always did exactly what I expected it to. But the reason I followed their advice was because I agree with you about the style.

Comment: @BillKarwin Looks like you cover a lot of good stuff in those slides. I'll check it out sometime. Thanks for sharing.